# How to write this in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have created an entity called CarInfo but I am not sure how to write this SQL in it's equivalent Linq form.

```
SELECT @PartKey = PartKey 
FROM CarInfo
WHERE CarKey = @CarKey
AND RegKey = @RegKey
AND TransactionDate = 
     (SELECT MAX(TransactionDate) 
      FROM CarInfo
      WHERE CarKey = @CarKey
      AND RegKey = @RegKey
      AND TransactionDate <= @TransactionDate)
```

Comment: The subquery contains either an unnecessary check: `AND TransactionDate <= TransactionDate`since this will always be true, or if you intended to link the 2 queries together you need to indicate which `TransactionDate` comes from which query

Comment: Sorry, it should have read AND TransactionDate <= @TransactionDate as I am passing this in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I probably shouldn't alter the logic of your original SQL statement, but it looks like its purpose is to provide the partkey from the nearest record at or closest in the past to a certain date.  If that is in fact the case, I would consider this:

```
var result =(from ci in ctxt.CarInfos
            where ci.CarKey == carKey
            && ci.RegKey == regKey
            && ci.TransactionDate <= transactionDate
            orderby ci.TransactionDate descending
            select ci.PartKey)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

result will be the partKey (or null if no records are found).  If you wanted all the records that matched that date then you will have to group them before the orderby.

Comment: Hi Dice, I get a couple of errors using your method. The where says carinfos does not take 1 arguments and the following line says operator == cannot be applied to operands of type string or int.

Comment: @Brian your variables (carKey, regKey, and transactionDate) must be of the same type as the corresponding columns in the database (if ci.CarKey is an integer, then carKey must also be an integer).

Comment: Thanks Dice, I always seem to miss the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from c in database.Cars
  where c.CarKey == carKey &&
  c.RegKey == regKey &&
  c.TransactionDate == database.Cars.Where(c => c.CarKey == carKey && c.RegKey == regKey && c.TransactionDate < transactionDate).Max()
  select c.PartKey;

foreach (var key in query)
{
    //Do your work
}

//or
var onlyKey = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Where:

1. database.Cars is your table, replace with EF or Linq2SQL accordingly
2. regKey, carKey, and transactionDate are local variable with your values
3. You need a Car class setup correctly with EF or Linq2SQL

Comment: Hi Jon, in your solution, does query = c.PartKey once executed?

Comment: It will be an IEnumerable of c.PartKey, you will need run a foreach over it or call query.FirstOrDefault(), whichever is applicable to your situation.  If c.PartKey is a string, you will get an IEnumerable<string>, and FirstOrDefault() will return a string or null if there were no results from the query.

Comment: Hi Jon, I get an error on the where saying Delegate...does not take 1 arguments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are some real Linq experts lurking around these parts, but this is an initial attempt that should really help you move forward:

```
var results = 
    from carInfo in Context.CarInfos 
    where carInfo.CarKey == carKey && carInfo.RegKey == regKey && 
        (carInfo.TransactionDate == (Context.CarInfos.Max(
            (item) => item.CarKey == carKey && item.RegKey == regKey && item.TransactionDate < transactionDate)))
    select carInfo.PartKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    from carInfo in context.CarInfo
    where carInfo.Key == carKey && carInfo.RegKey == regKey                              
&& carInfo.TransactionDate == (from c in carInfo
                              where c.CarKey == carKey && c.RegKey == regKey &&
                              c.TransactionDate <= transactionDate
                              select c.TransactionDate).Max()
    select carInfo.PartKey
```